# How to enable mono debugging mode for Process.Start()

Tags: c#, debugging, mono

I have a master process which launches some child processes using  `System.Diagnostics.Process` class and I cannot get stack trace info when a child process throws an exception.

Yes, I have .MDB files generated for my assemblies.

Yes, I launch the main process using `mono --debug`.

So, how to use `Process.Start()` in mono so that the new process was launched in debugging mode (or in the same mode as the current mono process was launched)?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are launching a new process, use a different port number as to not conflict with the already running mono debug process, i.e:  `mono  --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:63000 xxx.exe` and then connect the debugger to that ip/port address

Comment: RobertN, I do not need to remotely debug the new process. The question relates to the stack trace debugging info only.

Comment: The stack trace you need will come from connecting a debugger to the child process, your master process is never going to 'see' it. If that child process is another mono instance start it with the debugging option and connect a second mono debugger to it or create a new app domain in your   master app, load the child assembly and call its static main method, now the debugger attached to the master app will see it. If that child process is not a mono-based one, you can use `gdb` to attach to it (`gdb attach pid`) after you Process.Start() it. Remote debugging, no, my example is using localhost

Comment: I am not talking about using a debugger :) I am talking abount stack traces held by exceptions. Currently I cannot see source files and lines where exception did occured because `Process.Start()` does not propagate `--debug` option to child mono processes. This is the problem.

Comment: Process.Start() starts a TOTALLY separtate process (blocking or non-blocking), does not really matter if that process is another mono-based process or not. If the child process is a mono-based process, the parent process is not ever going to see mono exceptions from it. The best you could do is monitor its std-out/std-err and exit code.

Comment: Why you suppose I am trying to see exceptions of a child process from the parent one? :) Of course I am not. I am doing `try .. catch` in child processes and writing exceptions to the log file. So I can see exceptions but every line of a stack trace looks like `... [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0` and this is because child mono process does not inherit `--debug` command line option.

Comment: "child mono process does not inherit --debug", of course it would not... why don't you start that child process with `--debug` the argument: ;)

Comment: And if you can not control how you are starting mono in that child process, you can use the `mono-symbolicate` tool to add line numbers to a stack trace after the fact...

Comment: "why don't you start that child process with --debug the argument" - because I start it with Process.Start() (I need cross-platform way of launching processess). Under mono `Process.Start( string fileName )` requires an assembly name so I have no control over mono command line.